# Thymeleaf Validation

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am learning thymeleaf validation section and i got error like

**Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('jobtitle')" (authentication/contactus:19)**

My form has following field

```
        <div class="form50">
            <label for="contact.emailAddress"><span th:text="#{contact.email}">Email</span></label>
             <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="email"></span>
            <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" class="field50" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}? 'fieldError'" />
        </div>

        <div class="form50">
            <label for="customer.firstName"><span th:text="#{contact.jobtitle}">Job Title</span></label>
            <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('jobtitle')}" th:errors="*{jobtitle}"></span>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{jobtitle}" class="field50" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'fieldError'" />
        </div>

        <div class="login_register">
            <input class="register_button big red" type="submit" th:value="#{contact.contact}"/>
        </div>

    </blc:form>
```

when i remove jobtitle div its working fine

myvalidator class looks like following

```
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors, boolean useEmailForUsername) {
        ContactCustomerForm form = (ContactCustomerForm) obj;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "name.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "email", "emial.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "jobtitle", "jobtitle.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "country", "country.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "phone", "phone.required");
}
```

What is the issue i cant able to identify!!!!!!Please Help

Comment: The more interesting message is deeper in the stacktrace. Can you post the complete one?

Comment: Can you please verify your code first, seems like your form elements are little mixed up. And post whole form element...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is following line

```
<span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="email"></span>
```

it has to be

```
th:errors="*{email}"
```

same as this line in your code bellow

```
<span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('jobtitle')}" th:errors="*{jobtitle}"></span>
```